# why the edit on json files in eclipse not save?

Tags: json, eclipse

I am using Eclipse JavaEE , I create json file like this :

json_demo.txt

```
{
    "nameofclass":"Employee",
    "nameofmethod":"editFirstTime",
    "isstaticmethod":"false",
    "parameters":[ "x int", "y double", "date Data" ]
}
```

for example when I edit the value of "nameofclass" then the press "ctrl_s" then run my project the edit not save , so if I write :

```
"nameofclass":"Department",
```

after press "ctrl_s" and run my project the **"nameofclass"** take the old value **"Employee"** , so can any body help me to save the Edit on my json file in Eclipse JavaEE ?

update : this way I take the value :

```
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
                           {
                            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                                myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                            }
alert(myObj.nameofclass);
```

Comment: Are you sure you editing the right file?

Comment: yes I have only one json file in my project @jens

Comment: How do you *take* the value when you're running project?

Comment: I Edit my question and add the way which I take the value @ Aleksandr M